# What does the Gradient Stripes section mean in the Libre Office print preferences?

Tags: graphics, printing, libreoffice

[image]

I guess that Reduce Gradient means that it isn't as high quality, but what is the option for Gradient Stripes or Intermediate Colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient stripes determines how many different coloured stripes make up the whole gradient.

This is a gradient made in ink scape, then converted to 50 and 25 stripes. You can see the difference in quality of the three.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And this is an ink scape gradient then converted to an intermediate colour. What that means is it is the average colour.

[image]

[image]

Believe it or not that second box is all the same colour.